# Is it safe to drop a table column constraint in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I'm looking at a production table in postgres with the following constraint which due to third party collaboration we need to remove.

```
"customer_email_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (customer_email)
```

This is a production table, what risks are there if I remove the constraint?  If it causes problems can it be recreated after to an existing table, with existing data in it?

It looks like the command to drop the constraint is

```
ALTER TABLE your_table DROP CONSTRAINT customer_email_unique;
```

We're a React/ Node stack and I can see what the code is doing with regard to what will happen if the constraint is dropped, my lack of knowledge is more towards data and what happens if you drop a constraint.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is a production table, what risks are there if I remove the constraint? If it causes problems can it be recreated after to an existing table, with existing data in it?

The risk is that you'll drop the constraint and non-unique entries will be inserted. You won't be able to reapply the unique constraint without deleting the non-unique rows or updating them to be non-unique. Another risk it that you'll drop the wrong constraint, or reapply the constraint incorrectly. Finally, there may be code which assumes that column is unique.

To mitigate this risk, write a script to drop the constraint ("up"), and one to restore uniqueness and reapply the constraint ("down"). Test it on an equivalent table on a non-production database.

This is the general idea of [schema migrations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schema_migration). Every schema change is done by two scripts, an "up" script to apply the change and a "down" script to undo the change. Many ORMs, such as [typeorm](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm), support migrations. They make schemas reproducible so all environments know they have the same schemas, schemas can be tested, and in general mitigate the risk of schema changes.

Comment: thanks Schwern!  Great and detailed explanation